# I can't load a save model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tensorflow 2.11 in spyder with win10. I have a pre-trained model save in .h5 file but when I load, it isn't see in variable explore. The pre-trained model was train with owner metrics.

Here it's the code

The custom metric

```
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
  smooth = 1.
  Flatten
  y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
  y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
  intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
  score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) +     smooth)
  return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  loss = 1 - dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
  return loss
```

And the code

```
from keras.models import load_model
#model = load_model('D:\Preprocesamiento\FASE_III/ResdANet_org.h5', compile=False)
model.load_weights('D:\Preprocesamiento\FASE_III/ResdANet_org.h5')
model.summary()

#%%
# load the model
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('D:\Preprocesamiento\FASE_III/ResdANet_org.h5',custom_objects={'dice_coeff':dice_coeff},compile=False)

# compile the model
loaded_model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=['binary_crossentropy',dice_loss], 
              metrics=['accuracy',
                       tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                       tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                       dice_coeff])
```

I'm using too

```
def predict_segmentation(model, image):
    # Use the model to predict a segmentation mask
    mask = model.predict(image) 
    mask.shape()
    # Visualize the original image, predicted mask, and composite image
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 10))
    ax[0].imshow(image)
    ax[0].set_title("Original Image")
    ax[1].imshow(mask)
    ax[1].set_title("Predicted Mask")
    ax[2].imshow(image)
    ax[2].imshow(mask, alpha=0.5)
    ax[2].set_title("Composite Image")
    plt.show()
```

And show me the next ERROr

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(32, 256, 3)

When the input data is 256, 256, 3 and the image too. I don't understand whyy (32, 256, 3)

Comment: A stupid thing but are you sure `image` is of shape `(None, 256, 256, 3)`?

Comment: jejeje yes, I try resize the image (256,256,3) and resize (32,256,3) but it dont's work.